# How to change images in flexslider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexslider

I know this is a very basic question but it has me very confused - there's not much documentation that I could find about the flexslider. Also, I'm very new to this language, I'm a C++ / ASM type person but trying to get a webpage setup. The page is for an internet radio station. The slider is used to show the album covers of the currently playing, next, and later albums. The image names are 'hard-coded' in the slider which is fine if the images don't need to change. The problem is that the images do change every 3 minutes but the browser caches them so even if the image file contents change, the old image data displays.

I spent the last few weeks developing a Windows service that updates the actual image files (Playing.jpg, Next.jpg, etc.) from the SQL database (among other things) only to find out once the slider is initialized, the displayed images don't change.

Anyway, is the slider just used for 'static' images? Any advice as to how to update the images dynamically? php / js?

```
<li> <img src="Playing.jpg" alt="" >
   <div class="flex-caption">
      <h2>Now Playing</h2>
   </div>
</li>
```

Thank you!

Keeping the filenames the same but changing the image contents makes no difference. What's the general way of changing slider images dynamically? Code snippets would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the browser cache you can add a random query like that:

**PHP:**

```
<li> <img src="Playing.jpg?v=<?php echo rand(); ?>" alt="" >
   <div class="flex-caption">
      <h2>Now Playing</h2>
   </div>
</li>
```

**JS:**

```
<li> <img src="Playing.jpg" alt="" id="imageid">
   <div class="flex-caption">
      <h2>Now Playing</h2>
   </div>
</li>
<script>
document.getElementById("imageid").src="Playing.jpg?v="+Math.random();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding and the code snippets. I believe I had tried similar but it did not work - I will try again. Due to my last failed attempts, I am now actually wondering if the flexslider load the image files into memory after it is initialized and then just uses the memory image instead of reloading the images from the physical files. I think that goes to my lack of knowledge on this subject. Thank you again.

Comment: Do you want to change the image while reloading the page? or, you want to change the image without new loading/re-loading the page.  The method I provided will work on page loading or reloading. Every time you load/reload the page, the image will be changed. Yes, of course, the browser (not flex slider) saves the image into the memory. If you want to change the image without reloading the page, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Mehedi's answer is good but random strings can collide and `Math.random()` is returning a float, an integer would be better.
So, it is better to use server current UNIX time e.g.:

### PHP

```
<li>
  <img src="Playing.jpg?v=<?php echo time(); ?>" alt="" />
  <div class="flex-caption">
    <h2>Now Playing</h2>
  </div>
</li>
```

### JavaScript

```js
document.getElementById("imageid").src = `Playing.jpg?v=${Date.now()}`;
document.getElementById("imageid").alt = `Image Name: Playing.jpg?v=${Date.now()}`;
```

```html
<li>
  <img src="Playing.jpg" alt="" id="imageid" />
  <div class="flex-caption">
    <h2>Now Playing</h2>
  </div>
</li>
```

**However**, this is bad for the user as he is always downloading images. The best solution would be to change the filenames from database and pass that data somehow to your code (maybe an API endpoint or something).
Also, since images are changing every 3 minutes, you could set a cookie in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and check with it for intervals of 3 minutes before passing another time in your `<img>`.

Personally, I would go with an API-approach.

Comment: Thank you for ideas and the code snippets. I'll give them a shot.